# How to check AM and PM in the strings

Tags: php

I need some help with my code as I am not very good with this thing as I am new on this. I want to check the strings to see if the time1 and time2 is betwen `PM` and `AM` then do something.

```
$time_1 = $show_array[0][datetime];
$time_2 = $show_array[1][datetime];
```

Here is the results for the time1 and time2 strings:

```
10:00 PM
3:00 AM
```

Can you show me an example how I can check if the time1 and time2 have the strings `PM` and `AM`?

Comment: the question is "why"? any special reason? There could be a simpler method here than having to apply some form of filter.

Comment: what do you need to know for??

Comment: I sense a bit of hostility here. I posted a simple comment, I wasn't impolite nor did I say anything otherwise for me to deserve a comment such as yours.

Comment: Well I want to check if the strings is `PM` and `AM` so I can set to the previous day. Why do you need to know?

Comment: why not use a 24 hour format and check if there's a time difference? The DateTIme class is a good one to read up on http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php yet `date()` also has the 24 hour method you can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php  that's why I asked and wanted to possibly/hopefully save you some time/coding/regex where it may not be required.

Comment: @DannyWhite - the more context you provide to your question, the more help you can receive. As Fred -ii- points out, there is most likely a more efficient or concise solution to your problem. If you do not wish to learn of possible alternative approaches, then see my answer below. If you do, update your question, and we can go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `preg_match`:

```
preg_match('/am$/i', $time);  // returns 'true' if ends with 'am' OR 'AM'
preg_match('/pm$/i', $time);  // returns 'true' if ends with 'pm' OR 'PM'
```

Using `strtotime`:

```
$a = strtotime('10:00 PM');
$b = strtotime('3:00 AM');
$noon = strtotime('12:00 PM');

var_dump($a < $noon, $b < $noon);  // false, true
```

Using `DateTime`:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('h:i a', '10:00 AM');
var_dump($date->format('G') < 12);  // true
```